# add :before to an object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am trying to add a :before to a td element in my table with content same as the value as the th in the same column, i got to the point where i can change the value of the td but im stuck at adding the :before, here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
  var last = rows[0];
  var first = rows[1];

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var cell = last.cells[i];
    var value = cell.innerHTML;
    alert(value);
    first.cells[i].innerHTML = value;

  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>aa</th>
      <th>bb</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add :before to element with JavaScript. But you can do it with CSS:

```css
td:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<td data-content="content for :before">
  actual content
</td>
```

And then just change `data-content` attribute on `td` with JavaScript.